# SEO issues with Elm?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, javascript, googlebot, render

Do search engines, particularly Google, render JavaScript created from transpiled Elm code when crawling? Can they follow links, even internal that modify the existing page?

Comment: Why not test in [fetch and render tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) yourself. And provide a example of your internal links like(example.com/page#tab1) and how it changes the content on same webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they have been able to do this for a while now. HTML generated after the page load is crawled and the links can be followed. You can read more about this on Search Engine Land - http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157